# Differences between URI and URL

Tags: url, uri

I've read about this in so many web sites but none of them explicitly states the difference between URI and URL.

what are the specific differences? and can somebody give me examples for both URI and URL ..

Answer (score 0):

A URL describes the protocol as well.
For example, a URI might be **`myhost:8080/MyApp/dosomething`**.

And a URL can be **`http://myhost:8080/MyApp/dosomething`**

You can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier#Technical_view).